# Can I generate Clang AST matchers from template arguments?

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to use Clang AST matchers to find function decls based on a name and template arguments.

The signature of my method should look a bit like this:

```
getFunctionDecl<T>(std::string name) {
  // return the function with name "name" and signature T... 
}
```

So to find `int foo()`, the usage would be `getFunctionDecl<int()>("foo")`.

I know how to get functions by `name`:

```
 match functionDecl(hasName(name))
```

But I don't know what the best way to match the signature `T` is.

Is there a matcher like `hasSignature`?

```
 match functionDecl(allOf(hasName(name), hasSignature<T>()))
```

I could create `ParmVarDecl` objects myself, but I would like to avoid re-inventing the wheel if possible. There is also quite a bit of complexity here due to weird signatures like `const std::unique_ptr<const int*>&`, so I would prefer a well-tested solution.

Comment: Perhaps functionTemplateDecl could work here. you can check it out here: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html